# WordPress admin password in free acces

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a site that was develop 2 years ago. Today some guy said me that admin access of my site are in free access.

Site was developed by one small webagency. I checked in DB wp_users and saw only one fake user added couple years ago (it seems for testing). I do not see my actual admin acces at this table.

I am not sure how this happend. Where I can find my admin login/passwords? Any search on DB by login name do not give me any results.

WordPress version is 4.5.15

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the wp_users table, just modify the username and email directly in the database, then go to the site's forgot password page and reset your password.

Comment: 1. I cant see my actual username at wp_users. There is only one item made in 2016
2. I am afraid that admin login/password are really in free acces for all internet.

Comment: Then you need to reset the password of that existing password to be safe and scan the site for malicious code using https://sucuri.net/

Comment: everything is fine except outdated WP version. If someone interesting I used this link for scaning: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net